# Oracle getting slow

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

My DB is getting slow on particular weekdays like Saturday and Sunday. What will be the reason?

Database is Oracle 11g R1.
Operating system is Windows 2003 64 Bit Service pack 2.

Comment: You'll need to do more work than that. Imagine calling a car repairer and saying "My car is slow on saturday and sunday. Why?" :)
He might say "do you wear heavier boots during the week?"...

Comment: So much information missing about what your database actually does, during the week, at weekends, at night, during the day. At the least, describe what you mean by 'getting slow'. What makes you think it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a million things ..

- traffic patterns (although usually there is more traffic during the week, but that depends on your users)
- other things going on related to the DB (there may be DB backups etc.)
- other things going on on your server (again backups, others processes using ressources)

It would be very strange if this is directly related to your DB. AFAIK there is no `if dow='Saturday' then wait 5000 end`code in Oracle ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you run an AWR/ statspack report during the week when performance is good and compare that to an AWR/ statspack report from the weekend where performance is poor?  If the entire system is slow, the AWR/ statspack report should identify what the system is waiting on.